# How can I manipulate this nested Json data in Pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have multiple nested JSON objects which are extracted from the REST API and look like this:

```
{
"count": 2,
"value": [{
    "teamMember": {
        "id": "ID1",
        "displayName": "NAME1",
        "uniqueName": "UNIQUE1",
        "url": "URL1",
        "imageUrl": "ImgURL1"
    },
    "activities": [{
        "capacityPerDay": 3.5,
        "name": ""
    }],
    "daysOff": [{
        "start": "2021-11-15T00:00:00Z",
        "end": "2021-11-15T00:00:00Z"
    }, {
        "start": "2021-11-26T00:00:00Z",
        "end": "2021-11-26T00:00:00Z"
    }],
    "url": "URL1"
}, {
    "teamMember": {
        "id": "ID2",
        "displayName": "NAME2",
        "uniqueName": "UNIQUE2",
        "url": "URL2",
        "imageUrl": "IMAGEURL2"
    },
    "activities": [{
        "capacityPerDay": 2.9,
        "name": ""
    }],
    "daysOff": [{
        "start": "2021-11-12T00:00:00Z",
        "end": "2021-11-12T00:00:00Z"
    }, {
        "start": "2021-12-02T00:00:00Z",
        "end": "2021-12-02T00:00:00Z"
    }],
    "url": "URL2"
}]}
```

I want to extract some information from this object to end up with something like this:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuY0J.jpg)

How can I do that in pandas? any hints would be much appreciated!

Comment: The JSON sample seems to be in the wrong format, can you provide a valid sample?

Comment: I don't see any nested JSON in the example

Comment: @aaossa just edited the sample! sorry

Comment: @ThomasWeller I just edited the Json sample, it is nested in the "value" I believe, as far as i understand it at least

Comment: `value` is an array.

Comment: @ThomasWeller yet it's still vague for me how to access the data inside the array, any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a flat table as a result

```
|---|----------------|-------|------|-----|-------|---------|------|-----------|
| 0 | capacityPerDay | start | URL1 | ID1 | NAME1 | UNIQUE1 | URL1 | ImgURL1   |
| 0 | capacityPerDay | end   | URL1 | ID1 | NAME1 | UNIQUE1 | URL1 | ImgURL1   |
| 0 | name           | start | URL1 | ID1 | NAME1 | UNIQUE1 | URL1 | ImgURL1   |
| 0 | name           | end   | URL1 | ID1 | NAME1 | UNIQUE1 | URL1 | ImgURL1   |
| 0 | capacityPerDay | start | URL1 | ID1 | NAME1 | UNIQUE1 | URL1 | ImgURL1   |
| 0 | capacityPerDay | end   | URL1 | ID1 | NAME1 | UNIQUE1 | URL1 | ImgURL1   |
| 0 | name           | start | URL1 | ID1 | NAME1 | UNIQUE1 | URL1 | ImgURL1   |
| 0 | name           | end   | URL1 | ID1 | NAME1 | UNIQUE1 | URL1 | ImgURL1   |
| 1 | capacityPerDay | nan   | nan  | ID2 | NAME2 | UNIQUE2 | URL2 | IMAGEURL2 |
| 1 | name           | nan   | nan  | ID2 | NAME2 | UNIQUE2 | URL2 | IMAGEURL2 |
```

You may just use `pd.json_normalize()` with few `explode()` like this:

```
import pandas as pd

#your_json = {smth}
pd.json_normalize(your_json['value']).explode('activities').explode('daysOff').explode('activities').explode('daysOff')
```

Of course, there are many ways to write this more clearly, but at least now you know which direction to look in.

Answer (score 0):

You have regular JSON with an array. There's no nested JSON. You can access the contents of the array in a regular way.

```
json_string = '''
...    <-- put your JSON here or get the JSON string in a different way
'''
import json
json_object = json.loads(json_string)
print(json_object["value"][0])
print(json_object["value"][1])
```

Answer (score 0):

As the dictionary may contain more than 1 json values, my limited knowledge states we may have to use a loop, if someone else has a more efficient way, please do share it and enlighten us, but here is a working version of converting this raw json into the information you need.

```
import json

json_string={
"count": 2,
"value": [{
    "teamMember": {
        "id": "ID1",
        "displayName": "NAME1",
        "uniqueName": "UNIQUE1",
        "url": "URL1",
        "imageUrl": "ImgURL1"
    },
    "activities": [{
        "capacityPerDay": 3.5,
        "name": ""
    }],
    "daysOff": [{
        "start": "2021-11-15T00:00:00Z",
        "end": "2021-11-15T00:00:00Z"
    }, {
        "start": "2021-11-26T00:00:00Z",
        "end": "2021-11-26T00:00:00Z"
    }],
    "url": "URL1"
}, {
    "teamMember": {
        "id": "ID2",
        "displayName": "NAME2",
        "uniqueName": "UNIQUE2",
        "url": "URL2",
        "imageUrl": "IMAGEURL2"
    },
    "activities": [{
        "capacityPerDay": 2.9,
        "name": ""
    }],
    "daysOff": [{
        "start": "2021-11-12T00:00:00Z",
        "end": "2021-11-12T00:00:00Z"
    }, {
        "start": "2021-12-02T00:00:00Z",
        "end": "2021-12-02T00:00:00Z"
    }],
    "url": "URL2"
}]}

json_data=[]
count=json_string['count']
for i in range(len(json_string["value"])):
#    print(json_string['value'][i])
    display_name=json_string['value'][i]['teamMember']['displayName']
    activity_capacity=json_string['value'][i]['activities'][0]['capacityPerDay']
    days_start=json_string['value'][i]['daysOff'][0]['start']
    day_end=json_string['value'][i]['daysOff'][0]['end']
    url=json_string['value'][i]['url']
    json_data.append([count,display_name,activity_capacity,days_start,day_end,url])

print(json_data)
```